# Find local plane basis at a location using WGS84

Tags: coordinate-system, software-recommendations, wgs84

I have orientation data from a drone given as a quaternion with respect to the local reference system (Z is up, X is local east, Y is local north) which is the local tangent plane.  I want to express that same orientation with respect to the basis defined by WGS84. For that I would I need to find the basis for the local tangent plane at a latitude and longitude. With that at hand I could then find the transformation between the WGS84 basis and the local plane. Finally I can use that transformation to move my original quaternions to the WGS84 reference system.

Right now I'm assuming a spherical Earth and then the local tangent plane vectors are just $\vec{\phi}, \vec{\theta}, \vec{r}$. These are easy to find in any textbook/wikipedia. In theory I could do the same for an Earth described by a geodetic coordinate system but I'm having trouble finding the right equations and I'm afraid of how many subtle bugs I would introduce.

Do you know of any (preferably Python) off the shelf solution for what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

The correct coordinate system to describe WGS84 is a geodetic coordinate system as described in [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geodetic_coordinates) or this [ESA webpage](https://gssc.esa.int/navipedia/index.php/Ellipsoidal_and_Cartesian_Coordinates_Conversion).

The equations are a bit more hairy than for spherical coordinats but nothing that a symbolic algebra system can't take care of. For example using the sympy package:

```py
from sympy import Matrix, cos, sin, sqrt, symbols


def get_coord_functions_and_jacobian():
    # In order:
    # - lat
    # - long
    # - height
    # - semi-major axis
    # - eccentricity
    , , h, a, e = symbols(", , h, a, e")

    N = a / sqrt(1 - (e * sin()) ** 2)
    x = (N + h) * cos() * cos()
    y = (N + h) * cos() * sin()
    z = ((1 - e**2) * N + h) * sin()

    coords = Matrix([x, y, z])
    vars = Matrix([, , h])

    jacobian = coords.jacobian(vars)

    basis_vectors_ = jacobian[:, 0]
    basis_vectors_ = jacobian[:, 1]
    basis_vectors_h = jacobian[:, 2]

    return coords, [basis_vectors_φ, basis_vectors_λ, basis_vectors_h]
```